# Vue i18n including external JSON's with translations

Tags: javascript, docker, vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm using [Vue-i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n) package. In every component i include a JSON file with translations, like this:

```
// this is a Vue template: home.vue
<i18n src="../locales/pages/home.json"></i18n>
```

Locally it works fine.

But i'm storing JSON files with translations on another server, so this package won't work if i try to include an external JSON directly:

`<i18n src="https://example.com/translations/home.json"></i18n>`

Instead, i decided to get the files on the server side (using node), however i've faced an issue when i try to deploy my app in a docker container, because an app needs to be builded with `npm run build`, all of the files are already bundled in JS files after build, thus i cannot replace these JSON files with my node script.

Does anyone have an idea on how to reach my goal?

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution to this?